# NoSuchElementException Chrome v71 headless

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I use headless mode I get NoSuchElementException. I think it`s after browser update, but if you can, please help me.

```
"goog:chromeOptions": {
            "useAutomationExtension": False,
            "excludeSwitches": [
                "enable-automation"
            ],
            "extensions": [
            ],
            "args": [
                "--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36'",
                "--window-size=1920,1080",
                "--disable-infobars",
                "--disable-local-storage",
                "--disable-notifications",
                "--incognito",
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                "--incognito",
                "--mute-audio"
            ]
        }
```

In "headless" (add "--headless" to args) and "head" mode I find same element, but only in "head" it`s works.